# codeigniter check checkbox array if exist in database

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a form that contains checkbox array and I am trying to to check in database if a certain checkbox value exist, if not then insert it to database:

Here is my current code:

View Page:

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url('test/post_form')?>" method="post">  
<input type="text" name="full_name">
<input type="checkbox" name="subject[]" value="Algebra" > 
<input type="checkbox" name="subject[]" value="Trigonometry" > 
<input type="checkbox" name="subject[]" value="Geometry" > 
<input type="submit" name="submit">
```

Controller Page:

```
public function post_form()
{
$post_data = array(
'subject'=>$this->input->post('subject'),
'full_name'=>$this->input->post('full_name'),
);  

$this->load->model('subject_model');  
if($this->subject_model->check_subject($post_data)===true)  
 {  
  $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'Already Exist');  
  redirect('test/error_page');  
 }
else  
{  
  insert to database
}
}
```

Model Page:

```
public function check_subject($post_data=array())  
{
extract($post_data);  
foreach($post_data as $key=>$value)  
{  
$this->db->select('subject');
$this->db->where('subject',$value['subject']);
$this->db->where('full_name',$value['full_name']);
$this->db->from('subject_table');  
$query=$this->db->get();  

  if ($query->num_rows() > 0)  
  {
      return true;
  } 
  else  
  {
  return true;  
  }

}
```

sample Scenario:

- lets say trigonometry exist in db,
- if i check all the checkboxes and submit, it still inserts trigonometry.
- however if algebra exists in db,
- and i check all the checkboxes, it says already exists.
- looks like only the first value is being checked for duplication.

Comment: So what's the actual problem? Getting errors? Not working correctly? What happens?

Comment: Why do you define your `$post_data` array without `$this->input->post('subject')` array? I don't see any input data for `$this->input->post('dept')` anywhere...

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to track the subjects found in data base in separate array and return with the result, it may look like something like that you can set it to `True FALSE` combination or anything else whatever suits you

```
public function check_subject($post_data=array())  
{
extract($post_data); 
$subjects=array(); 
foreach($post_data as $key=>$value)  
  {  
$this->db->select('subject');
$this->db->where('subject',$value['subject']);
$this->db->where('full_name',$value['full_name']);
$this->db->from('subject_table');  
$query=$this->db->get();  

  if ($query->num_rows() > 0)  
      $subjects[$value['subject']]=true;
  else  
      $subjects[$value['subject']]=FALSE; 
  }
return $subjects;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually your Subject is posted as an array so u check it this way

```
public function check_subject($post_data=array())  
{
$val = " '". implode( "', '",$post_data['subject']) ."' " ;

$this->db->select('subject');
$this->db->where(" subject in {$val} ");
$this->db->where('full_name',$value['full_name']);
$this->db->from('subject_table');  
$query=$this->db->get();  

  if ($query->num_rows() > 0)  
  {
    return true;
  } 
  else  
  {
    return false;  
  }

}
```

Check it i think it will work